# How to add Yes/No column in a Make Table query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a current Make Table query.  I'd like to add a column to that query that creates a Yes/No field with a checkbox in the new table.  I'd also like all the boxes to be checked (or a Yes value) by default.  I'm not sure how to add to the SQL statement to properly create that scenario.  Here's my current code without the new "Reportable" column:

```
SELECT 
    tChart1.[Original Except No] AS [Reportable Except No], 
    tChart1.[Original Document Number] AS [Reportable Document Number],
    tChart1.[Original Travler] AS [Reportable Travler], 
    tChart1.[Original Exception Amount] AS [Reportable Exception Amount],
    tChart1.[Original Destination] AS [Reportable Destination], 
    tChart1.[Original Exception Nights] AS [Reportable Exception Nights],
    tChart1.Explanation AS [Reportable Explanation], 
    tChart1.Reason AS [Reportable Reason], 
    tChart1.[Original Comments] AS [Reportable Comments], 
    tChart1.[Original Campus] AS [Reportable Campus], 
    tChart1.[Original Date] AS [Reportable Date], 
    tChart1.[Original Document Number] & "+" & [Original Travler] & "=" & [Original Exception amount] & "+" & [original destination] AS ID 
INTO tChart1_Reportable
FROM tChart1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `SELECT ... INTO` query is simply not capable of doing what you want.

You can use DDL to add a column and set its `DEFAULT`:

```vba
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "ALTER TABLE tChart1_Reportable ADD COLUMN Reportable YESNO DEFAULT -1;"
```

Then execute an `UPDATE` to store True in the existing rows:

```vba
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "UPDATE tChart1_Reportable SET Reportable = True;"
```

However, if you want the field to appear as a checkbox, those steps may not be enough.  You can open the table in Design View, select the field, then its Lookup tab and select Check Box from the Display Control dropdown.

You can do it with VBA code instead ...

```vba
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim prp As DAO.Property

Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdf = db.TableDefs("tChart1_Reportable")
Set fld = tdf.Fields("Reportable")
For Each prp In fld.Properties
    If prp.Name = "DisplayControl" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If prp Is Nothing Then
    Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("DisplayControl", 3, 106)
    fld.Properties.Append prp
Else
    fld.Properties("DisplayControl").Value = 106
End If
```

Comment: Ok.  I'm getting a Property not found. (Error 3270) on this part: CurrentDb.TableDefs("tChart1_Reportable").Fields("Reportable").Properties("DisplayControl").Value=106

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that.  The updated code works whether or not the property already exists.